# adding img to grid column

Tags: php, image, user-interface, grid, atk4

Is it possible to add an image (pdf print) to grid column with on click javascript action?
Like:

```
$g->addColumn('button','edit','Edit');
```

but with img html element.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

```
$g->addColumn('template','pdf_print')
    ->setTemplate('<a href="'.
        $this->api->getDestinationURL('pdfprint').
        '?id=<?$id?>"><img src="printicon.png"></a>');
```

Alternative approach is to define your own formatter. I'm also showing how you can add a global javascript handler to a column but still pass the "id" of record clicked.

```
function format_pdfbutton($column){
    $this->current_row[$column]=
        '<img src="printicon.png" class="print_'.$column.'"/>';
}
function init_pdfbutton($column){
    $this->js('click')->selector('.print_'.$column)->frameURL('Print Frame',
    array(
        $this->api->getDestinationURL('print'),
        'id='>$this->js()->_selectorThis()->closest('tr')->attr('del')
    ));
}

$g->addColumn('pdfbutton','print_my_pdf');
```

I haven't tested the code above, but you can also look at "Grid" source and how regular buttons are defined (Grid::format_button,  Grid::init_button).